# Importing HTML table into OO Calc as UTF8 without converting to entities

Tags: utf-8, html-entities, html-table, openoffice-calc, libreoffice

I have a problem when opening a HTML table in OpenOffice or LibreOffice if it contains UTF8 extended characters like ÅÄÖåäö.

When opening the table into M$ Excel it works as intended but I can't make OO do the same thing.

By converting all extended characters to its HTML entity eqivalent &Aring; etc. it works but it would be nice to get the correct characters directly.

Is there anyone who knows what I should do?

The following content I have in a file called excelsample.xls and if I open that with OO Calc it will not look nice.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/vnd.ms-excel" charset="UTF-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Prawn sandwich</td><td>Räksmörgås</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The meta tag should be `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8">`. Try fixing that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your meta tag is malformed and OO doesn't probably recognize the html5 charset tag.

So fix it with:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: bullseye!  UPVOTED! :)

Comment: Thank you so much! This applies to websites downloaded from Wikipedia, so very relevant.