# Encoding UTF-8 when exporting HTML table to Excel

Tags: javascript, html, excel, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to export an HTML table to Excel using javascript. This is the javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tableToExcel = (function() {
          var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
            , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
            , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
            , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
          return function(table, name) {
            if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
            var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
            window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
          }
        })()
</script>
```

This is my header

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/vnd.ms-excel;" charset="UTF-8">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

This is my table

```
<table id="tblExport">
   <tr>
      <td>José</td>
      <td>María</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

And this is the button which triggers the export

```
<input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('tblExport', 'W3C Example Table')" value="Export to Excel">
```

I can't export the UTF-8 characters correctly, like é or í. I try this [Importing HTML table into OO Calc as UTF8 without converting to entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14199428/importing-html-table-into-oo-calc-as-utf8-without-converting-to-entities) but not works. I have MS-Excel 2010 and Win7 64 bits.

How can I do to export UTF-8 chars correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 52):

First: Your header is malformed. It should be:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8">
```

And second: It should be into your template, because it contains charset information for Excel.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tableToExcel = (function() {
          var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
            , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
            , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
            , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
          return function(table, name) {
            if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
            var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
            window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
          }
        })()
</script>
```

Comment: Can you share the simple solution that you found? Tks!

Comment: Thanks for sharing the simple solution :D

Comment: so what was the simple solution?

Comment: Any news about the "solution more simple" ?? ^_^

Comment: your answer is good , and thé function you wrote was helpful for me +1

Comment: MS IE does not support `data` protocol for all use cases. ["For security reasons, data URIs are restricted to downloaded resources. Data URIs cannot be used for navigation, for scripting, or to populate frame or iframe elements."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc848897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). So no, no solution for IE with this approach.

Comment: This solution didn't properly work for me. To properly encode the UTF-8 string I used [b64EncodeUnicode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding#The_Unicode_Problem) instead of base64() defined in the snippet.

Comment: @Franck Valentin: Maybe, maybe not. This "solution" is outdated. There are multiple JavaScript libraries which are able creating **really** Microsoft Excel files. No need for foisting Excel that crude mixture of HTML and XML.

Answer (score 4):

You could prepend the content string with the UTF-8 BOM definition:

```
function ExportToExcel() {
    var BOM = "\uFEFF";
    var htmltabel = document.getElementById("tabella_finale");
    var html = htmltabel.outerHTML;
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,'+ encodeURI(BOM + html));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function exportData(report_id){
    var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById(report_id).innerHTML], {
        type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8;"
    });
    saveAs(blob, "Report.xls");
}
```

Takes table data as plain text and save as Excel without encoding problem

Comment: I struggled with making something like this work, there's also an "encoding" property on Blob.  But, every excel program is going to interpret "html saved as .xls file" differently, so who knows.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change default file name [according to @Axel Richter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25730640/6778436), try this:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.download = 'filename.xls';
...
link.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
link.click();
...
```

replace *window.location.href* with *link.href*

Answer (score 0):

I will cite again a respect that was indicated above. You need to include the meta tag code inside the head tag:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<!--This is what you should include-->
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8">
<!---->
<title>Ver Listado Pago</title>
<link href="/Images/Decretos.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/booostrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/booostrap/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/booostrap/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

This has worked for me. But IE and WIN10 have some conflicts for download because of the xls extension. 
However, the problem of special characters is corrected

Answer (score 0):

after googling I found a solution edit file /tableExport/tableExport.js line 280

```
var base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) } // New base64

// var base64data = "base64," + $.base64.encode(excelFile); OLD LINE
var base64data = "base64," + base64(excelFile); // New line with new base64
```

that is all

Answer (score -1):

Use the code below in the var uri:

```
var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8;base64,'
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uueVi.png)