# Arabic encoding when exporting HTML table to Excel

Tags: javascript, html, excel, encoding, utf-8

I'm using this function to export [xls](/questions/tagged/xls) from [html](/questions/tagged/html) table

```
var tableToExcel = (function(e) {
    //getting values of current time for generating the file name
    var dt = new Date();
    var day = dt.getDate();
    var month = dt.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = dt.getFullYear();
    var hour = dt.getHours();
    var mins = dt.getMinutes();
    //var postfix = day + "." + month + "." + year + "_" + hour + "." + mins;
    var postfix = day + "." + month + "." + year;
    //creating a temporary HTML link element (they support setting file names)
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    //getting data from our div that contains the HTML table
    var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var table_div = document.getElementById('reptoxlsx');
    var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
    var sheetname = $("#chainnames").children(":selected").text();
    a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
    //setting the file name
    a.download = sheetname + ' _ ' + postfix + '.xls';
    //triggering the function
    a.click();
    //just in case, prevent default behaviour
    //e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

after a lot of search about (how to export data in Arabic format) I found that I have to change Charset of the file, So, I found that code

```
var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8;base64,'
```

- ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42661534/2080202

So I added to my code:

```
var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8;base64';
```

but when I tried to export XLS file from OnClick event:

```
$(document).on('click','#exportreptoexcel',function(){
        tableToExcel();
    });
```

the file (browser) gives me:

> Failed - Network Error

So I edit mine by deleting **;base64** changing the code to:

```
var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8';
```

Exporting/Downloading the file was great, but Arabic still the same:

[image: Arabic issue in XLS after Export from HTML table]

So, the question is, how to export Arabic in Excel using the giving code?

thanks in advance

---

**EDIT 1**
I found another [script](/questions/tagged/script) and it worked greaaat with Arabic charset, BUT without supporting file name variable.

```
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})()
```

to export [xls](/questions/tagged/xls) file, just call it in OnClick event:

```
$(document).on('click','#exportreptoexcelfile',function(){
    //working great with Arabic without filename
    var sheetname = $("#chainnames").children(":selected").text();
    tableToExcel('reptoxlsx',sheetname);

});
```

-- the Question is: How to make this Function support "fileName" as a variable?!

thanks again

Comment: are you using `csv` file format ?

Comment: if you're asking about the output file>> So, No, the output file is xls

Comment: please see **EDIT 1**

Comment: @Hossam Set `a.href` and `a.download` from first example instead of `window.location.href`.

Comment: YES, I found it, I just posted an answer for it :))) thanks a lot for help, Now, I have a script with filename and support Arabic charset ;)

Comment: if we want to export in csv format how we can do?

Comment: I think you can just try to change data_type from `data:application/vnd.ms-excel` to `data:text/csv`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for the function in **EDIT 1**

```
    //window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))

    var dt = new Date();
    var day = dt.getDate();
    var month = dt.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = dt.getFullYear();
    var postfix = day + "." + month + "." + year;
    var result = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = result;
    a.download = name + ' _ ' + postfix + '.xls';
    a.click();
    return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should encode text as base64:

```
var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8;base64';
...

var table_html_base64 = btoa(encodeURIComponent(table_html)
  .replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g, function (match, code) {
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(code, 16));
  }));
...

a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html_base64;
```

Comment: unfortunately the file damaged..  you can see the image of it from here=> https://imgur.com/a/IRe4w

Comment: please see **EDIT 1**

Answer (score 0):

```
    let name = 'test';
    let table = 'table1'; // table id
    let uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,';
    let template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>';
    let base64 = function (s) {
        return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));
    };
    let format = function (s, c) {
        return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; });
    };
    if (!table.nodeType) { table = document.getElementById(table); }
    let ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML };

    let hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
    hiddenElement.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
    hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
    hiddenElement.download = `${name}.xls`;
    hiddenElement.click();
```

Comment: add some explainations

Comment: this code create excel file with web format via a <table>. base64 encoding for unicode character and hiddenElement for create hidden <a> with download link and click that without user interference.

usage: create table in html and pass that id to this function & set download file name