# export HTML table to Excel correctly with €/$/£ Symbol

Tags: javascript, excel, character-encoding

I'm using this function by export html table to excel file.

```
function ExportToExcel() {
    var htmltabel = document.getElementById("tabella_finale");
    var html = htmltabel.outerHTML;
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,'+ encodeURI(html)); 
}
```

it works correctly but when I open .xlsx file , euro symbol doesn't show correctly.
It shows

> â‚¬ 90.15

instead of

> €90.15

Comment: This appears to be JavaScript, not PHP, correct? Also, you do understand that this is not creating an Excel file, it is creating an HTML file that the client is encouraged to treat as one.

Comment: This seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25730008/231316

Comment: ok but how can I resolve this issue or do you know other function that can do this?

Comment: It might be easier to export to csv, Excel will have no issues reading it..

Comment: It must be excel

Comment: Please only tag questions with languages that are relevant to the code you provided. If you are hoping or willing to accept code in additional languages, that is not what the tags are intended for.

Comment: i resolve it bu using tabe 2 excel grab it from github https://github.com/linways/table-to-excel. It works like a charm

Comment: @chris-haas, I have a really simple solution but you closed the question! I can't post the answer

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've seen it right now!